# How to give a type to a literal?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to tell SQL-Server that a number is of a given type. Here is a little example:

```
drop table if exists test
declare @i int = 100000

            SELECT 4 pwr, cast(10000 * @i as bigint) val into test    
insert test SELECT 5,     cast(100000 * @i as bigint)              
insert test SELECT 6,     cast(1000000 * @i as bigint)
insert test SELECT 7,     cast(10000000 * @i as bigint)
insert test SELECT 8,     cast(100000000 * @i as bigint)
insert test SELECT 9,     cast(1000000000 * @i as bigint)
insert test SELECT 10,    cast(10000000000 * @i as bigint)

select * from test
```

In the table are only row with pwr 4 and 10. SQL-Server seems to give a numeric literal a datatype depending on the value. High values will be converted into numeric, smaller into int.

Casting to a type is a way to handle this.

```
insert test SELECT 6, cast(cast(1000000 as bigint) * @i as bigint) test
```

Is there a way to tell SQL-Server the datatype of a constant other than casting it every time you use it?

Online-Help is unclear here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql)
as it says 'decimal constants are represented by a string of numbers that are not enclosed in quotation marks and contain a decimal point.'. It should say '.. or represented by a numeric value that does not fit into the int range.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not, if you don't count implicit conversions (i.e. `DECLARE @x TINYINT = 3`). Some types do have separate ways of writing literals (numeric, floating-point, binary, etc.), but this is not the case for the various integral types. The only way to have them distinguished is to explicitly convert constants (which would otherwise by default be of either `INT` or `NUMERIC` type).

You are correct that the documentation is lacking in this regard. Without a decimal point, the type depends on whether it'll fit in an `INT`:

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CONVERT(SQL_VARIANT, 0), 'BaseType')
-- int

SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CONVERT(SQL_VARIANT, 2147483648), 'BaseType')
-- numeric
```

There is no way to get `BIGINT` out of this other than a conversion.

Comment: Also of note is that the casting or converting will make your number nullable.

Comment: @Medinoc: under what circumstances expressions end up as nullable or not is its own can of worms and probably deserves a question all on its own. The only way I know of to make arbitrary expressions typed as non-`NULL` is to use `ISNULL`: `ISNULL(CONVERT(BIGINT, 42), CONVERT(BIGINT, 42))`. Note that `COALESCE` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting too late
It is as easy as

```
declare @i bigint = 100000;
```

That cast is happening after the multiplication.

The last works because 10000000000 is bigint.

First works because the multiplication result is still int.

Even with `declare @i int = 100000;` this works.

```
insert #test SELECT 5,  cast(100000 as bigint) * @i;
```

This has NOTHING to with decimal.
10000 is integer so it does integer math the result is integer.
100000 is integer so it does integer math problem is the result is not integer
10000000000 is bigint so it does bigint math

Per correction from Jeroen 10000000000 is decimal.  Decimal math is valid and then the result is successfully cast to bigint.

Comment: `10000000000` is `NUMERIC(11, 0)`, not `BIGINT`, per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql#converting-integer-data).

Comment: @JeroenMostert OK then it works because it is valid decimal math that converts to bigint